# How to import and use scipy.spatial.distance functions correctly?

Tags: image-processing, numpy, scipy

```
   from scipy.spatial.distance import seuclidean #imports abridged
   import scipy


   img = np.asarray(Image.open("testtwo.tif").convert('L'))

   img = 1 * (img < 127)

   area = (img == 0).sum() # computing white pixel area

   print area

   areasplit = np.split(img, 24) # splitting image array

   print areasplit


  for i in areasplit:
  result = (i == 0).sum()
  print result             #computing white pixel area for every single array

  minimal = result.min()      
  maximal = result.max()

  dist = seuclidian(minimal, maximal)

  print dist
```

I want to compute distances between array elements, produced from splitting an image. Python can`t recognize the name of a distance functions (I have tried several of them and variuos approaches to importing modules). How to import and call these functions correctly? Thank you

Comment: Are you getting specific errors?

Comment: Please show the *exact* code that you used, and the complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated what the error is, but you are using numpy as well and I can't see an import for that
Try

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
```

Then try

```
dist = scipy.spatial.distance.euclidian(minimal, maximal)
dists = scipy.spatial.distance.seuclidian(minimal, maximal, variances)
```

Note - the standardised euclidean distance takes a third parameter.

Comment: This won't work. `import scipy` does not import all the subpackages.  You must use `import scipy.spatial` (or some variation such as `from scipy import spatial`, and the drop the prefix `scipy.` and just use `spatial.distance`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the specific syntax `from scipy import spatial` in order to use those functions. Then use `spatial.distance.your_distance_function` in order to call the function.